# Выдает ошибку "не удается найти node в path. node установлен ?"

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

[image: Такое происходит при нажатии Launch Program и при установке точек остановки.]

Такое происходит при нажатии Launch Program и при установке точек остановки.

Answer (score 0):

По поводу вопроса:
Ответ уже в нем. Установить и добавить.

Но! В вашем случае это не поможет,
тк необходима отладка клиентского (в браузере) кода.
Это можно сделать в браузере.
А можно и в ide, как вы и пытаетесь, но с помощью расширения.

Вам поможет изучение этой статьи.
[https://medium.com/devschacht/отладка-javascript-в-google-chrome-и-visual-studio-code-c2f07603a5b8](https://medium.com/devschacht/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0-javascript-%D0%B2-google-chrome-%D0%B8-visual-studio-code-c2f07603a5b8)

Если вам не понятно что такое веб сервер и чем клиентский код отличается от серверного .... Да и вообше, вот классный сайт, рекомендую !

http://learn.javascript.ru